# formvalidation use two regex pattern

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin

i'm using [formvalidation](http://formvalidation.io/validators/regexp/) plugin and i want to have two regex pattern. one to detect 6 characters with at least 1 digit and another one to detect spaces in password the user entered. the error message should be different for both of them this is one i need two patterns.

so far iv'e tried to use one javascript pattern

```
validators: {
        regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-z\s]+$/i,
            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
        }
   }
```

and one inline pattern

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName"
      data-fv-regexp="true"
      data-fv-regexp-regexp="^[a-z\s]+$
        data-fv-regexp-message="The full name can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only" />
```

when i have 1 javascript and 1 inline it will only use the inline.

and i also tried two javascript pattern but this is an error

```
validators: {
        regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-z\s]+$/i,
            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
        },
        regexp: {
            regexp: different regex,
            message: 'different message'
        }
   }
```

does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: i updated my questions so you can see what i've tried

Comment: @user2587454 Do you mean using 2 regex on the same field ?

Comment: @user2587454 `to detect spaces in password the user entered` Did you mean to allow using space in passwords or the opposite ? if you mean the first one, you can just use the [stringLength](http://formvalidation.io/validators/stringLength/) validator, it will count the string length and will allow using spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

The only way to use two regex on the same field is by using the `callback` validator.

I suggest you to follow these steps:

- First, check the length of your password, if it exceeds 6 characters long, exit with error (*You don't need to use a regex to check for spaces if you do allow the use of them*).
- Second, count the number of used digits, if that number is < 1, exit with error (*Here you can use a regex*).

See the following code:

```
$('#yourForm')
  .formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        password: {
            // When a field has multiple validators, validation for this field will be
            // terminated upon the first encountered error. Thus, only the very first
            // error message related to this field will be displayed to the user.
            //
            // See verbose docs: http://formvalidation.io/settings/#form-verbose
            verbose: false,
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: "The password is required and cannot be empty."
                },
                callback: {
                    callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                        // Count the number of digits in your password
                        var digitsCount = value.search(/[0-9]/);

                        // Check for 6 characters length.
                        if (value.length !== 6) {
                            return {
                                valid: false,
                                message: "The password must be at least 6 characters long."
                            }
                        }

                        // Check the number of used digits
                        if (digitsCount < 1) {
                            return {
                                valid: false,
                                message: "The password must contains at least one digit."
                            }
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

#### Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/5xjnv8mb/

#### References:

- Callback validator's documentation: http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/